# Selecting entire Store vs Selecting Individual values with React UseSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux

Scenario:
Hello, so I have this scenario where I have a redux store with many fields, say 30.
And most of those fields are used in the ReusableChildFormComponent, some are used in the ParentComponent, and a handful of them are used in the Grandparent component.

```
<GrandparentComponent>
    <Provider/Context>
        <ParentComponent>
            <ResuableChildFormComponent props={...} />
        </ ParentComponent >
    </ Proivder/Context>
</ GrandparentComponent>
```

My Approach:
To avoid having to pass down so many fields via props, I thought it would be cleaner and faster (dev time-wise) to use a selector that contains everything in the store (i.e. `const formStore = useSelector(state => state.formStore);` to then create a Provider/Context at the Grandparent level that contains the entire store so that only the fields that each level needs can be accessed and avoid unnecessary prop drilling.

Question:
I would like to know if there are any efficiency backlashes to this approach and if this is better than prop drilling it. Or any other clean, efficient solutions: Essentially avoiding me having to implement this where Grandparent selects each individual value from the Store, then passes all those values down to the parent via props, which then passes most of all those values down to the child via props.

Comment: Why do you not access the store in the grandchildren components instead of the grandparent component?

Comment: because it is reusable, so the values in it (determined by props) can very depending where it is being used @phry

Answer (score 0):

If you englobe `GrandparentComponent` in the Redux `Provider`, you should be able to access any value you need using `useSelector` inside any of the components within that tree. No need for prop drilling.

Comment: Grandparent Component is where the Provider is created. Thus, it already has access to the values through the useSelector performed earlier.

Comment: The Redux Provider is created in the Grandparent component? Still, if it's wrapping the children, useSelector will work.

Comment: wouldnt that be too many subscriptions to the store?